# Can't get basic web servers working on EC2 RedHat

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, tornado

I'm trying to get some basic Python web servers (Flask, Tornado) turned up on the EC2.

On the Amazon-flavored Linux AMI (**Amazon Linux AMI 2013.03.1**) they work no problem, but the same web servers installed on the RedHat quicklaunch AMI (**Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4**) don't work at all- All I get is connection failure errors when I try to browse to them.

Both these servers share the same security group, with the relevant ports (5000, 5010) open, so I'm trying to understand why RedHat would not be not working.

Comment: Did you open the firewall ports?

Comment: What kind of connection error do you get?  Timeout or reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has happened to me before, too.  And to other people.

It's probably the firewall.  You might need to run

```
system-config-firewall-tui
```

or

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp ––dport 5000 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp ––dport 5010 -j ACCEPT  
/sbin/service iptables save
```

to reconfigure the firewall.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=359166

http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/post/36757573573/how-to-open-tcp-port-4502-on-rhel-6-firewall-on-amazon